# How to reuse LINQ subqueries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am writing a query which contains several join operations. I want to write this query in a function so that I can call this function everytime I need this query. My function and the query are as follows. Since I have several join operations and I don't want to define a complex return type, I keep the return type just `IQueryable`.

```
 private IQueryable getMySubQuery(MyContext db)
 {
       var query = db.Orders
                         .Join( ... )
                         .Join( ... )
                         .Join( ... );
       return query;
 }

public IQueryable <MyType> getData()
{
     var db = ... 
     ... 
     ...
     var query = getMySubQuery(db)
                     .Select(  /// ERROR ???

    return query;
}
```

I am getting an error: System.Linq.IQueryable doesn't contain a definition for `Select`.

I understand that if I define the return type of `getMySubQuery()` method as `IQueryable <SomeType>`, it will solve the problem. But the problem is I have to define a very complex type containing 50 fields. I don't want to do the projection in `getMySubQuery()` function.  Is there any way I can solve it without creating the complex type? I want to use `IQueryable` rather than `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Is `TResult` of the last join an anonymous type?

Comment: What if you did `IQueryable<T> GetData(DBSet<T> entity)` and instead of getData() you did `GetDataFor(db.Orders)`? This is off the top of my head so I'm not posting as an answer in case it's rubbish!

Comment: @Erik No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Magnus The last join is not anonymous type. But the result of subquery of anonymous type.

Comment: If it is not anonymous I don't see why you cant return IQueryable of that type-

Comment: @Magnus I can return IQueryable. But I can't use the Select extension method from my second function. Please see the statement where I am getting the error.

Comment: Well you cant return `IQueryable` of an anonymous type and use it further. (The only way would be to materialize the query and access the properties using reflection) I think you are going to have to bite the bullet and create the 50 property class.

Comment: If you use Dynamic Linq Library. you can use IQueryable.Select method to do projection out of getMuSubQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this sample code is truly representative of your actual code then the problem is you're returning an `IQueryable`, not an `IQueryable<T>`. The reason you're doing that is because you're trying to use an anonymous type as the result of `getMySubQuery`, but it's not possible to share anonymous types across method boundaries. If you truly want to do this, you need to create a type that represents the data that is currently being returned as an anonymous type and then make sure you change `getMySubQuery` to return `IQueryable<T>` of that type.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:  `var query = getMySubQuery(db).Tolis()
                     .Select(  /// No ERROR!`

Comment: Note that getMySubQuery is of type IQueryable but not IQueryable<T>; thus I can't use ToList() method. Moreover, if I create the list, further operations will be done in-memory which will not be efficient since I have lots of records.